# How to "hijack" and modify command line parameters

Tags: python

I am working on a script that is supposed to serve as a (very thin) wrapper for another script. e.g.

```
./myprogram_wrapper.py -a -b varc -d vard
```

should internally do some processing that modifies `varc` and `vard` and invokes

```
./myprogram.py -a -b varc_modified -d vard_modified
```

An important detail is that some of the parameters (e.g. `-a` and `-b`) are optional.

What I'm struggling with is:

1. How to get the command line parameters to get the initial command line. Is using the `sys.argv` array the best option? Or can `argparse` help?
2. How to invoke the other script with a modified set of parameters?

Comment: What is the entry point for `myprogram.py`? If it's structured such that you can call `main(args)`, you can just `import myprogram.py` in `myprogram_wrapper` and call it with the parsed, updated arguments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think it is. After a block of processing the parameters, using argparse.ArgumentParser we have:


    # Calling main
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv)


So in principle the approach you suggest could work. Can you give a quick example ? newbie here :)

Comment: That won't be quite so easy, as it looks like the argument parsing is rolled into `main`. Do you have any control over the wrapped script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `myprogram.py` is structured something like:

```
import argparse
import sys

def main(args):
    """Does all of the work."""
    ...

def parse_args(args):
    """Parses the arguments."""
    ...
    return parsed_args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(parse_args(sys.argv))
```

Then this becomes very easy, `myprogram_wrapper.py` can look like:

```
import sys

from myprogram import main, parse_args

def modify_args(args):
    """Modify the arguments."""
    parsed_args = parse_args(args)  # reuse the original parser
    ...  # add your own changes
    return modified_args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(modify_args(sys.argv))
```

The other advantage of structuring `myprogram.py` like that is that it's also easy to separately test the different functional elements of the script. I have used a similar structure in [my own project](https://github.com/textbook/py_wlc/blob/develop/py_wlc/data/webtag_parser.py#L274) and [tests](https://github.com/textbook/py_wlc/blob/develop/tests/data/test_webtag_parser.py#L57).

Comment: Ok, Just to check a couple of details:
- looking at the example there shouldn't be any main or parse_args function function on the `code` myprogram_wrapper.py , otherwise there's name collision, right ?

Comment: Yes, unless you `import myprogram` and access the versions there via e.g. `myprogram.parse_args`